# solr query precedence

Tags: solr

I made a solr query in two ways

way 1:

status="sent" AND hostname:"host.com" AND log_date:[2011-12-08T00:00:00Z TO 2011-12-08T23:59:59Z]
Result: 328232

way 2:

hostname:"host.com" AND log_date:[2011-12-08T00:00:00Z TO 2011-12-08T23:59:59Z] AND status="sent"
Result: 62359

I verified through grep etc in the original data set and found that the second query way 2: gives the correct count. Is this how the query is supposed to be or I have a malformed query ?

Another question that I have is that I am using solr only for indexing and searching, thus is it possible for me to tell solr somehow do not calculate score and not to worry about score when returning the results ? will it make things faster for me ?

Comment: `status="sent"` is an invalid query; it should be `status:sent`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should look into using [Solr Filter Queries](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) to help limit your results. I am unsure of what your main query would be and what could be passed as filter queries as all of the current search fields appear to be just filters on given field values. So perhaps you would do a query using the log_date as the main query term as follows:

```
 q=log_date:[2011-12-08T00:00:00Z TO 2011-12-08T23:59:59Z]&fq=status:"sent"&fq=hostname:"host.com"
```

You may want to follow the guidance in the wiki link above and combine some or all of the filter query values.

As far as the question on score, AKAIK the score is always calculated by Solr as it is using this to return and rank relevant items in the index. So I do not think it is possible to turn it off or to gain any performance from not calculating score. You can not specify score as field to return if you do not need it by changing your `fl` parameter.

Comment: thank you paige and mauricio for your replies, the query syntax was incorrect as paige indicated.